# Is there any function available to find string position after specified index in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

The function available in Postgres:

```
strpos(string, substring)
```

eg:

```
strpos('my name is database', 'm')
```

returns: 1

My requirement is to return the position of the substring after a specified index:

```
strpos(string, substring, 5)
```

eg:

```
strpos('my name is database', 'm', 1)
```

should return: 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[STRPOS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) accepts only two arguments. But you can chain a call to substring and easily achieve your objective.

```
SELECT STRPOS(SUBSTRING('my name is database',2), 'm')
```

Note that postgresql strings start from 1 and not 0 so you have to put 2 instead of 1 in the above query. Of course the result is relative to the new string 'y name is database' so you will have to add 1 to the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and its working also, but don't we have some more simple solution as using this on large string makes it a lot complicated.
Just like CHARINDEX in SQL SERVER.

Comment: glad to have helped. I guess not, but you could quickly write a stored function that does this.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is looking for a proper function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STRPOSWPOS (p_String VARCHAR, p_searchString VARCHAR, p_startIndex INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
RETURNS INT
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_Return INT;
BEGIN
    p_String:=LOWER(p_String);
    p_searchString:=LOWER(p_searchString);
    v_return:= 
        CASE WHEN STRPOS(SUBSTRING(p_String, p_startIndex), p_searchString) > 0 AND p_startIndex = 0 THEN
                STRPOS(SUBSTRING(p_String, p_startIndex), p_searchString)
             WHEN STRPOS(SUBSTRING(p_String, p_startIndex), p_searchString) > 0 AND p_startIndex > 0 THEN
                STRPOS(SUBSTRING(p_String, p_startIndex), p_searchString) + p_startIndex - 1
             ELSE 0
        END;

    RETURN v_Return;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```