# Postgres user defined function to remove a substring from a string

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.6 and I am looking to create a user defined function that will remove text between 2 different characters. I have searched the internet high and low to no avail. Consider the following demo below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_between(
                               _original_string
                             , _start_delete_character text
                             , _end_delete_character text
                              ) RETURNS TEXT language sql AS 
$$
...
$$


SELECT remove_between('origi<stuff and junk>nal str<junk>ing','<','>')
```

> Yields: original string

Where I am stuck is I could find the length of the entire string and the positions of the of the first `<` and the last `>` but then it would take off too much.

Comment: You're not trying to manipulate xml, are you?

Comment: Why not find the position of the first (not last) `>` as well? Or alternatively, the position of the first `>` [after the position of the first `<`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504465/1048572)

Comment: I am not. The <> are just the characters I chose

Comment: `select regexp_replace('origi<stuff and junk>nal str<junk>ing', '<[^>]*>', '', 'g');`

Comment: Abelisto, that worked. I am gonna use that to answer this question.

Comment: PS: Note that you will need to escape some special characters like `[](){}.*+?\` etc using backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will get the job done. A special thanks to Abelisto for the help in the comments.

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_between(
                               _original_string text
                             , _start_delete_character text
                             , _end_delete_character text
                              ) RETURNS text language sql AS
$$
    /*
    ==================================================
    Author:     dvandenbosch
    Created At: 7/14/2020
    Where Used:
    Usage: SELECT remove_between('origi<stuff and junk>nal str<junk>ing','<','>')
    ==================================================
    */
select regexp_replace(_original_string,_start_delete_character || '[^>]*' || _end_delete_character, '', 'g');
$$;
```

Comment: Wrong. Find the mistake by yourself.